# Create full screen XAML element

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

Just starting to play around with the Windows 8 SDK.

Trying to create a TextBox that fills up the whole screen. Unfortunately at different resolutions the TextBox does not fill up the screen.

How do I bind the width and height of the TextBox to the width and height of the screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't set the width and height of the TextBox in the xaml.  Instead, set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to Stretch.

Answer (score 9):

I got it to bind properly like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
...
</Grid>
...
<TextBox x:Name="MainContent" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MyGrid}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MyGrid}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF7A7A7A" FontSize="18.667"><TextBox>
```

Which is binding it to the size of the grid in the layout. This works by binding the Height and Width properties of the TextBox to the ActualHeight and ActualWidth values of the Grid. The ElementName of the binding links to the grid's x:Name property.

Comment: don't use ActualHeight/Width in binding statements...bad practice

Comment: Can you say why? And provide a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Try binding to [Window.Current.Bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.bounds.aspx).  It has Height, Width, X, and Y among other properties.